# Android xamarin build apk file?

Tags: android

I have a problem when exporting apk file with xamarin form project, file size is too large. Without a linker with a blank application, its capacity is 65 Mb. After I used the linker: Sdk and User Assemblies the capacity has dropped to 11 Mb (it is still huge for a blank application). I have read through some articles about skip unused libraries such as Mono.android and mscorlib, when I inserted the configuration "Skip linking Assemblies -> Mono.Android.dll; mscorlib.dll" File size remains unchanged. Can the file size be reduced again? Or is it a minimum or average file size when exporting to apk? Anyone can help me? Sorry for my bad english.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/377990760)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimum file size of the apk is 15Mb in xamarin forms.

try this:
Select SDK assemblies option in *Android --> Properties --> Android Options --> Linker*.